# How to replace the value of a dataframe column with the value of another column using groupby.first()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, pandas-groupby

I have a df like this:

```
               Value1     Value2
2008-01-01       -1          4
2008-01-01       -1          5
2008-01-03       -1          6
2008-02-25        0          7
2008-02-26       -1          8
2008-02-27        0          9
2008-03-02        5         10 
2008-03-16       -1         11
2008-03-17       -1         12 
2009-04-04       -1         13
2009-04-07        0         14
```

I want to check the **first** `value1` of every Year-Month. If it's < 0, I want value2 to replace with value1. How can I do that?

In this example, the result should be:

```
               Value1     Value2
2008-01-01       -1         -1
2008-01-01       -1          5
2008-01-03       -1          6
2008-02-25        0          7
2008-02-26       -1          8
2008-02-27        0          9
2008-03-02        5         10 
2008-03-16       -1         11
2008-03-17       -1         12 
2009-04-04       -1         -1
2009-04-07        0         14
```

Because only `2008-01, 2009-04` **first** `value1` are negative, `2008-2, 2008-03` **first** `value1` are positive, just leave it.

I used:

```
g = df.groupby([df.index.year,df.index.month])

if g['value1'].first() < 0:
   g['value1'].first() = g['value2'].first()
```

it doesn't seem to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach with `groupby().head()` to extract the index and `loc` to update:

```
s = df.groupby(df.index.to_period('M'), as_index=False).head(1)
df.loc[s[s['Value1'].lt(0)].index, 'Value1'] = df['Value2']
```

Output:

```
            Value1  Value2
2008-01-01       5       5
2008-01-03      -1       6
2008-02-25       0       7
2008-02-26      -1       8
2008-02-27       0       9
2008-03-02       5      10
2008-03-16      -1      11
2008-03-17      -1      12
2009-04-04      13      13
2009-04-07       0      14
```

Comment: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. Doesn't work on my real df.

Comment: @saga see update. However, I suspect your data has duplicated index.

Comment: Yes, if there's duplicated index (see update), what can I do?

Comment: `reset_index()` so you got an `index` column and use `s=df.groupby(df['index']....` instead?

Comment: Once I reset index column, the original datetime index column will become an ordinary column. df['col_name']to_period('M') will have AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_period'. Also I can no longer see the year by df['col_name'].year. But while it was index column, I could see the year by df.index.year

Comment: `df['col_name'].dt.to_period('M')`, not `df.index.to_period`

Comment: df['col_name'].to_period('M') --> AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_period'

Comment: It's the original column `Value2`, can you double check for typo again :D

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
year_month = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m')
#format the date so its simpler to find where the changes occur
rows_diff = np.flatnonzero(year_month[:-1]!= year_month[1:])+1
#see where the Value1 is 0 in the first row
m = df.iloc[rows_diff, 0] == 0
#set those values to whatever Value2 is
df.loc[m.index, 'Value1'] = df.loc[m.index, 'Value2']
```

---

```
print(df)

              Value1  Value2
2008-01-01      -1       5
2008-01-03      -1       6
2008-02-25       7       7
2008-02-26      -1       8
2008-02-27       0       9
2008-03-02      10      10
2008-03-16      -1      11
2008-03-17      -1      12
2009-04-04      13      13
2009-04-07       0      14
```

Comment: if I used groupby.first() and know which ones are < 0 already, how can I replace the value based on that? The one above is just an example, in my real df, there is different numbers of rows for each year-month. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach. I hope it is useful for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2008-01-01','2008-01-03','2008-02-25','2008-02-26','2008-02-27','2008-03-02','2008-03-16','2008-03-17','2009-04-04','2009-04-07'],
                   'value1':[-1,-1,0,-1,0,5,-1,-1,-1,0],
                   'value2':[5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
df_a = (df.groupby(['year','month'])['day'].first()).reset_index()
df_a['aux'] = True
df_output = df.merge(df_a,how='left',on=['year','month','day'])
df_output['value1'] = np.where((df_output['aux'] == True) & (df['value1'] < 0),
         df['value2'],
         df['value1'])
df_output = df_output.drop(columns=['year','month','day','aux'])
print(df_output)
```

Output:

```
        date  value1  value2
0 2008-01-01       5       5
1 2008-01-03      -1       6
2 2008-02-25       0       7
3 2008-02-26      -1       8
4 2008-02-27       0       9
5 2008-03-02       5      10
6 2008-03-16      -1      11
7 2008-03-17      -1      12
8 2009-04-04      13      13
9 2009-04-07       0      14
```

Comment: If theres more than 1 row with the same dates (as shown in the update). It doesn't seem to work. How to fix? Thanks.

Comment: As @QuangHoang stated, your index/`date` column must be duplicated. Will try to update later today or tomorrow